# Please identify this burnt SMD component in this LED driver PCB

Tags: identification, surface-mount, repair, component-values

This is an LED driver labeled as ED-SC 50W1200 (on the plastic housing) and no data is written on the back side of the PCB.

The other side of the PCB is immersed in a black resin that is now locked as a solid and bound to all the components on the top side so I can not remove it without damaging the plastic housing, but if that's the option I'll definitely do it.

[image: image of a PCB with a burnt out component marked]

The right side of the image is the bottom cover of the plastic housing that I have opened and in this side-by-side view, I also marked the mirrored area of the excessive heat of the component also burnt the plastic cover, so that's obviously one burnet out component if not the only one.

The LED Panel that was consuming the power of this unit started to go on/off a couple of days ago like 10 times a day until it stopped turning on, The LED strips of the luminaire are healthy and I'm not sure if this is the only failed component.

if you are 100% sure that finding and replacing this item won't fix the device or in general you advise me not to pursue this repair then please enlighten me, otherwise help me find and replace this component. here's a closer image:

[image: close up of a burnt out SMD component on a PCB]

It's probably the same as the other one nearby, readable as "IR00" or "1R00", but not sure and I don't know what's that.

Comment: Google 1R00 smd resistor... Get replacement... No? Did you try to measure and see how it's behaving? Having more resistance than it should is bad.  Having less might mean there's something else in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it failed from **very** high current (such as shoot-through). The duplicate circuit above suggests a half-bridge driver similar to a PC power supply, and perhaps the 0.25Ω resistor (3 R750 in parallel) is the load current sense resistor.

Almost surely the MOSFET or BJT it was connected to has also failed. That doesn't mean it's not repairable, but I'd not expect replacing the resistor to fix it, probably at least one and maybe several semiconductors more would be required. The other 1Ω resistor may have failed too. Unless you can access the top of the board I would call this unrepairable and cut my losses.